# When "i" reaches higher than 9, it fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, increment

The code below works fine until the "i" gets to 10.

divCount equals 11.

I added an `alert(i);` after the `++i` which confirmed that 10 was reached then nothing happened. Not even updateVer was called.

```
<script>

var divCount;
var mcsUrl;
var i = 0;  

//Count number of Divs
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  divCount = $("div").size();

  myLoop(); //update mcs versions
});


function myLoop () {           
    ++i;

    mcsUrl = document.getElementById('url'+i).innerHTML;
    updateVer(mcsUrl);
}

function updateVer(a) {

    $.getScript(a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js", function(){

        document.getElementById("version"+i).innerHTML = mss_version;

        if (document.getElementById("version"+i).innerHTML != "9.7j") {
            document.getElementById("version"+i).style.color = "#FF0000";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("version"+i).style.color = "#006633";
        }

        if (i < divCount) {
        myLoop();
        }
    });
}


</script>
```

Comment: 1) where is your html code? 2) why do you mix pure js selectors and jquery? 3) most probably you do not have an element with corresponding id.

Comment: Have you tried opening the debugger (F12) and checking to see if you have an error message?  That might tell you immediately where your problem is.

Comment: @Cheery "version10", "url10", "version11", "url11" exist in the HTML.

Comment: @Lochemage , yes, there are no JS errors showing in the debugger

Comment: can you provide your html for this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.getScript(a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js", function(){` was failing so I needed to add code to compensate for that:

So it now looks like:

```
$.getScript(a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js")
        .done(function() {
            document.getElementById("version"+i).innerHTML = mss_version;

            if (document.getElementById("version"+i).innerHTML != "9.7j") {
                document.getElementById("version"+i).style.color = "#FF0000";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("version"+i).style.color = "#006633";
            }

            if (i < divCount) {
                myLoop();
            }
        })
         .fail(function() {
            document.getElementById("version"+i).innerHTML = "FAIL";

            if (i < divCount) {
                myLoop();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

arrange your counting...

```js
function myLoop () {           
   

    mcsUrl = document.getElementById('url'+i).innerHTML;
    updateVer(mcsUrl);
  
   ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough context to solve whatever issue it is that you're having. For instance, what is the contents of `a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js"`? That being said, here's a few tips to help debug.

1) Comment out or delete lines of code until it starts working. Maybe start by reducing `updateVer` to just:

```
function updateVer(a) {
    $.getScript(a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js", function(){
        if (i < divCount) {
        myLoop();
        }
    });
}
```

2) Check your browser's debug console. See if it is showing any error messages.

3) The `success` callback for `$.getScript` only runs when the remote script downloads successfully. Are you sure that script #10 isn't giving you something like a 404 error?

Comment: I have divs that start "url" and finish with 1-11 and I have spans that start "version" and finish with 1-11. 

The output I receive up until 10 is as expected